# flutter validation error how to hide automatically?

Tags: flutter, validation

I want to automatically hide this error message or disappear after a few seconds

[image]

I tried to make it disappear automatically by adding a delayed task, but it didn't work

Comment: I'm sorry my title is wrong,The correct title would be flutter validation errorText how to hide automatically?

Comment: I think you can combine focuseNode changed with a timer

Comment: I haven't used it yet focuseNode，I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

add `autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction` like this:

```dart
TextFormField(
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
)
```

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't go away

Comment: can you share the code.

Comment: Using `onUserInteraction` will not vanish your test field validation message after some time, rather it will vanish your validation message when user enter something again to the field.

Comment: Yes, of course I know, but what I want is for it to disappear automatically after a few seconds without the user typing it

Comment: how can it disappear when it is not valid.

Comment: But if your focus has left the input box, and the input box has no data, wouldn't it be weird not to disappear?